# (Easier) reading of microcontroller hardware registers in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Specifically, I am using RP2040, which is an ARM Cortex M0+ microcontroller, which I debug over a USB `picoprobe` (connecting over SWD to my RP2040 target, and controlled by `openocd` in Windows 10 MINGW64) - which also provides a bridge to `gdb`, so I can debug the microcontroller. However, I'm mostly interested in a generic approach, applicable to any microcontroller (even if I would appreciate pointers to RP2040 or Cortex specific solutions).

So, let's say I want to read the register `UARTFR` - from https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf :

[image: UARTFR RP2040 datasheet]

First of all, I can do `info registers` (which changes per-core, that is, per-thread) in an active `gdb` session:

```
(gdb) thread 1
[Switching to thread 1 (Thread 1)]
...
(gdb) info registers
r0             0x0                 0
r1             0xa5a5a5a5          -1515870811
r2             0x10000000          268435456
r3             0x2                 2
r4             0xa5a5a5a5          -1515870811
r5             0x10002909          268445961
r6             0x16d               365
r7             0xe000ed00          -536810240
r8             0xffffffff          -1
r9             0xffffffff          -1
r10            0xffffffff          -1
r11            0xffffffff          -1
r12            0x100029f1          268446193
sp             0x2000b490          0x2000b490
lr             0x200011bb          536875451
pc             0x200011ba          0x200011ba
xPSR           0x61000000          1627389952
msp            0x20041fd0          0x20041fd0
psp            0x2000b490          0x2000b490
primask        0x0                 0
basepri        0x0                 0
faultmask      0x0                 0
control        0x2                 2
```

... however, these are what I would call "CPU" registers (e.g. program counter `pc`) - and in this case, I need to read a hardware peripheral (UART) register, that is, `UARTFR`.

The canonical way to access the `UARTFR` register in `C` via `pico-sdk` is:

```c
extern uint32_t my_fr;

// ....
uint32_t my_fr;

my_fr = uart_get_hw(uart0)->fr;
```

... however, unless you already include a global variable like the above in your code (and make sure that the compiler doesn't optimize it away), you'll have quite a hard time looking at `UARTFR` in a `gdb` session. For one, the above allows you to print the value of `my_fr` global variable - but if `UARTFR` register changed in the meantime, `my_fr` won't "know" about it, unless it gets assigned again.

Then, `uart_get_hw` is in [uart.h](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/f396d05/src/rp2_common/hardware_uart/include/hardware/uart.h), defined as:

```c
static inline uart_hw_t *uart_get_hw(uart_inst_t *uart) {
    uart_get_index(uart); // check it is a hw uart
    return (uart_hw_t *)uart;
}

// ... where ...:
static inline uint uart_get_index(uart_inst_t *uart) {
    invalid_params_if(UART, uart != uart0 && uart != uart1);
    return uart == uart1 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

So, as `static inline`, `gcc` will optimize these functions away, so there are no such symbols (of course, this is a Debug build I'm testing) visible in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) p uart_get_hw
No symbol "uart_get_hw" in current context.
```

... and even `uart0` is a `define` in [uart.h](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/f396d05/src/rp2_common/hardware_uart/include/hardware/uart.h):

```c
#define uart0 ((uart_inst_t *)uart0_hw) ///< Identifier for UART instance 0
```

... and those do not end up as symbols available to `gdb`:

```
(gdb) p uart0
No symbol "uart0" in current context.
```

Interestingly, there are two struct types involved here - one ends up as "incomplete" in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) ptype uart_inst_t
type = struct uart_inst {
    <incomplete type>
}
(gdb) ptype uart_hw_t
type = struct {
    io_rw_32 dr;
    io_rw_32 rsr;
    uint32_t _pad0[4];
    io_ro_32 fr;
    uint32_t _pad1;
    io_rw_32 ilpr;
    io_rw_32 ibrd;
    io_rw_32 fbrd;
    io_rw_32 lcr_h;
    io_rw_32 cr;
    io_rw_32 ifls;
    io_rw_32 imsc;
    io_ro_32 ris;
    io_ro_32 mis;
    io_rw_32 icr;
    io_rw_32 dmacr;
}
```

... and the other does indeed list UART registers - and `fr` is there as well - but I can't do much reading from a struct description.

Anyways - I thought, maybe I could skip over all of this figuring out of the right incantation, and instead refer to something like [regs/uart.h](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/f396d05/src/rp2040/hardware_regs/include/hardware/regs/uart.h), where we have:

```
...
// =============================================================================
// Register    : UART_UARTFR
// Description : Flag Register, UARTFR
#define UART_UARTFR_OFFSET _u(0x00000018)
#define UART_UARTFR_BITS   _u(0x000001ff)
#define UART_UARTFR_RESET  _u(0x00000090)
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Field       : UART_UARTFR_RI
// Description : Ring indicator. This bit is the complement of the UART ring
//               indicator, nUARTRI, modem status input. That is, the bit is 1
//               when nUARTRI is LOW.
#define UART_UARTFR_RI_RESET  "-"
#define UART_UARTFR_RI_BITS   _u(0x00000100)
#define UART_UARTFR_RI_MSB    _u(8)
#define UART_UARTFR_RI_LSB    _u(8)
#define UART_UARTFR_RI_ACCESS "RO"
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Field       : UART_UARTFR_TXFE
...
```

Now, first I cannot really tell if `UART_UARTFR_OFFSET _u(0x00000018)` represents an absolute address - probably not (especially considering there's one `UARTFR` register for each of the two UART hardware instances); but if it was, I could read it like this in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) p /t *0x00000018
$4 = 11101
```

Anyways, the most generic way to address this I can imagine, is simply find (or generate with a script) some kind of a `#define` list of registers, and - considering that as preprocessor constructs, `#define`'s do not end up as visible symbols in Debug builds of C code - have them *somehow* imported "directly" in `gdb`: so ultimately I'd be able to do (assuming `UART0_UARTFR` is the actual address of the `UARTFR` register of the UART hardware device `UART0`):

```
(gdb) p /t *UART0_UARTFR
$4 = 11101
```

... and in that way, read the `UARTFR` register "directly" and "easily".

What options, if any, do I have of doing this in `gdb`?

Comment: From `uart.h`: `#define uart0 ((uart_inst_t *)uart0_hw)` - does GDB see the `uart0_hw` symbol?  It looks like this should be a global pointer that points to the uart h/w.  My guess is `(gdb) print ((uart_hw_t*) uart_hw)->fr` might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - unfortunately '`No symbol "uart0_hw" in current context.`'; [hardware/structs/uart.h](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/f396d05/src/rp2040/hardware_structs/include/hardware/structs/uart.h) has `#define uart0_hw ((uart_hw_t *)UART0_BASE)`, where [addressmap.h](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/f396d05/src/rp2040/hardware_regs/include/hardware/regs/addressmap.h) has `#define UART0_BASE _u(0x40034000)`, so no dice with these either

Comment: I think macros are only included in the debug information at higher debug levels for some reason, you should try compiling with `-g3` and see if the macros are now available to you.